# Agrupar registros de una tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1;
```

Por lo que muestra esto:

```
Empresa | Empleado
-------- ---------
pepsi   | jose
-------- ---------
pepsi   | pedro
-------- ---------
pepsi   | juan
```

Lo que quiero que muestre es esto:

```
Empresa | Empleado
-------- ---------
pepsi   | jose

        | pedro

        | juan
-------- ---------
```

Intenté con esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1 GROUP BY Empresa;
```

Pero solo muestra el primer empleado:

```
Empresa | Empleado
-------- ---------
pepsi   | jose
```

Comment: Lo que quieres no se puede en BBDD, tienes que hacerlo con codigo en otro lenguaje de programación.

Comment: ¿Por que requieres este tipo de consulta?. Puede que esta no sea la solución ideal para tu necesidad, podríamos plantear otra solución.

Comment: Necesito mostrar una tabla en php con ese formato y estoy buscando como ahorrarme código

Comment: Se puede perfectamente obtener todos los empleados de la empresa x en una sola fila usando GROUP_CONCAT combinado con GROUP BY , agruparías por id de empresa y usarías un separador para cada empleado, por ejemplo este `|` y luego lees los valores en PHP usando `explode`. Si estuviera en mi PC te haría un fiddle de ejemplo, pero desde el móvil es complicado. Lo que quieres hacer es muy fácil.

Comment: No se puede hacer lo que tu quieres en SQL. Talvez la explicacion que diste no tiene nada que ver con lo que requieres. Ser mas objetivo.

Comment: Tu última consulta debería marcar un error `SELECT * FROM tabla1 GROUP BY Empresa;`, esto es porque todos los campos deben estar en la agrupación, si alguno no se encontrara no vas a poder correr la consulta.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Empresa, GROUP_CONCAT(Empleado)
FROM NOMBRE_TABLA
WHERE ID_EMPRESA = EMPRESA_NECESITAS 'Opcional,Solo si ocupas una empresa 
                                      especifica'
GROUP BY Empresa
```

Cuando tengas tu nueva tabla o resultado, lo separas con un *split* en tu código, usando como separador el carácter (`,`).

Espero y te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

En el siguiente ejemplo se agrupan los libros usando un campo llamado `ean`. Se usa `GROUP_CONCAT` combinado con `GROUP BY`, para obtener los datos concatenados, pero separados por un carácter cualquiera, en este caso uso `|`... Luego, en PHP, mediante `explode`, puedo leer por separado los diferentes libros pertenecientes a cada `ean`. En tu caso, `ean` equivaldría a la columna empresa.

El resto, sería cuestión de adaptar el código.

Espero te sirva.

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/euus-831a)**</kbd>

**Código:**

```
<?php
require "util/public_db_info.php";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user_name, $pass_word);
echo "<pre>";

/**
 *  Verificar si hay datos  
 *  Y  sacar el  contenido  usando foreach
 *  Nótese el uso de  count($arrDatos)  para contar el total de registros
*/



$sql = "SELECT id, ean, GROUP_CONCAT(title SEPARATOR '|') as libros FROM books WHERE ean=:ean1 OR ean=:ean2 GROUP BY ean;"; 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(":ean1",4);
$stmt->bindValue(":ean2",1);


$stmt ->execute();
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($arrDatos)
{
    echo "SE ENCONTRARON  ".count($arrDatos). " REGISTROS AGRUPADOS\n\n";
    print_r($arrDatos);    

    foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
    {
        echo "\n\nLIBROS CON  EL  EAN : ".$row["ean"]."\n\n"; 

        //Aquí  dividimos los datos usando el separador
        $arrLibros=explode("|",$row["libros"]);
        foreach ($arrLibros as $libro){
            echo $libro."\n";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "No hay datos";
}

echo "</pre>";

$pdo = null;


?>
```

**Resultado**

```
SE ENCONTRARON  2 REGISTROS AGRUPADOS

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 400
            [ean] => 1
            [libros] => Tú eres el Camino|Cruzando el umbral de la esperanza
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38053
            [ean] => 4
            [libros] => Hamlet|Romeo y Julieta|Lo que el viento se llevó|No hay amor más grande|El Principito|El Quijote
        )

)


LIBROS CON  EL  EAN : 1

Tú eres el Camino
Cruzando el umbral de la esperanza


LIBROS CON  EL  EAN : 4

Hamlet
Romeo y Julieta
Lo que el viento se llevó
No hay amor más grande
El Principito
El Quijote
```